# Parsing the web page response as Json, in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a java code:

```
URL oracle = new URL("https://x.x.x.x.x.x.-001");
System.out.println(oracle.openStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
```

Which is opening the connection and printing the contents of it. The contents are indeed Json. The output is something like:

```
{
  "merchantId": "guest",
  "txnId": "guest-1349269250-001",
}
```

I wish to parse this in [json](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) simple jar. I changed the code loop like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        obj.put("Result",inputLine);
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. The output I'm getting is:

```
{"Result":"}"}
```

Comment: Could it be that comma at the end of `"txnId": "guest-1349269250-001",` is giving you problems?

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, please post the stack trace.

Comment: Do you want to convert output to json object or reading output??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`JSONParser#Parse()`](http://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.html#parse%28java.io.Reader%29) method or the [`JSONValue#parse()`](http://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/org/json/simple/JSONValue.html#parse%28java.io.Reader%29) method :

```
URL oracle = new URL("https://x.x.x.x.x.x.-001");
System.out.println(oracle.openStream());
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream());

Object json = JSONValue.parse(in);
```

Comment: This works, but lets say I need to access `txnId`, doing `json.txnId` does throw an error.

Comment: You need to cast the json-object to an appropriate instance class. Take a look at the examples at http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples . 

In your case, it looks like an JSONObject is appropriate: JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(in);

Comment: After that, you can probably write json.get("txnId"); to access the txnId field.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're following [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) on how to parse a JSON string?

By the looks of it you have to obtain the entire string and call a `JSONParse#parse()` on it, but your code is filling up a `HashMap` (`JSONObject`'s parent class) with each of the lines of the JSON. In fact it stores just the last line because you're calling `put()` with the same `"Result"` key on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You should read whole contents to String variable first and parse it to json. Be careful of `""`(double quote). Java uses `\"` for double quote. Like.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonSimpleExample3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        //String str = "{\"merchantId\": \"guest\",\"txnId\": \"guest-1349269250-001\",}";

        //intilize an InputStream
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("file content".getBytes());

        //read it with BufferedReader and create string
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));// Instead of is, you should use oracle.openStream()
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

        // parse string
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());

            String merchantId = (String) jsonObject.get("merchantId");
            System.out.println(merchantId);
            String txnId = (String) jsonObject.get("txnId");
            System.out.println(txnId);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but lets say I need to access `txnId`, doing `json.txnId` does throw an error

Answer (score 0):

try this link its really helpful if you are going to be logging in or staff like that
[Java Json simple](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-json-simple.jsp)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ParseJson1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/genres.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=2";
    /*
     * {"title":"Free Music Archive - Genres","message":"","errors":[],"total" : "161","total_pages":81,"page":1,"limit":"2",
     * "dataset":
     * [{"genre_id": "1","genre_parent_id":"38","genre_title":"Avant-Garde" ,"genre_handle": "Avant-Garde","genre_color":"#006666"},
     * {"genre_id":"2","genre_parent_id" :null,"genre_title":"International","genre_handle":"International","genre_color":"#CC3300"}]}
     */
    try {
        String genreJson = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
        JSONObject genreJsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(genreJson);
        // get the title
        System.out.println(genreJsonObject.get("title"));
        // get the data
        JSONArray genreArray = (JSONArray) genreJsonObject.get("dataset");
        // get the first genre
        JSONObject firstGenre = (JSONObject) genreArray.get(0);
        System.out.println(firstGenre.get("genre_title"));
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}